# How does one set column width with Excel Interop?

Tags: excel, f#, excel-interop

I succeeded in writing to an `Excel` range, setting font color, etc. using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` library. One thing I was not able to do: setting column width. Could not find F#-specific documentation and adapting what I found for C# does not seem to work. For example, this code has no effect:

```
worksheet.Columns.AutoFit()
```

and this line of code does not even compile:

```
worksheet.Columns.[1].Columnwidth <- 15.0
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, working with Excel from F# is much easier with the help of [ExcelProvider](http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider/).

However, given you realize the intricacies of dealing with [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) from F#, operating with bare Excel is not something *too* complicated.

As you did not provide enough details for pointing out what exactly is wrong with your own attempts, here is a self-contained snippet demonstrating the manipulation with a worksheet column width, including visual demo:

```
#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
open System
let ex = new ApplicationClass(Visible=true)
let exO = ex.Workbooks.Add()
let exOWs = exO.Worksheets.[1] :?> Worksheet
exOWs.Name <- "TestSheet"
let col1 = exOWs.Columns.[1] :?> Range
let oldW = col1.ColumnWidth |> unbox
printfn "Current width of column 1 is %f" oldW
col1.ColumnWidth <- 15.0
let newW = col1.ColumnWidth |> unbox
printfn "New width of column 1 is %f" newW
printfn "Press any key to exit"
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
exO.Close(false, false, Type.Missing)
ex.Quit()
```

Running the above `fsx` script with `FSI` on a box having Excel installed should produce the output similar to one below:

```
--> Referenced 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll'

Current width of column 1 is 8.430000
New width of column 1 is 15.000000
Press any key to exit
```

Before stopping the script you may want to locate the opened Excel application window and observe that the first column width has really changed.

**UPDATE:** Covering `Autofit` part of the original question: the important tidbit to recognize is that fitting of range's cell widths and heights may be done only *after* the range is filled. Applying `Autofit()` to an empty range is of no use, while for an already filled range it works as expected.

Let's fill the first 4 columns of our sample worksheet's row 1 with strings of different length and then apply `Autofit` by placing the following after the line showing `newW` value:

```
let rowContents = "Our widths are flexible".Split(' ') in
    (exOWs.Rows.[1] :?> Range).Resize(ColumnSize=rowContents.Length).Value2 <- rowContents
exOWs.Columns.AutoFit() |> ignore
```

and observe the visual effect:
[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I will look into ExcelProvider. I did not know I had to downcast to `Range`. Is there a way to automatically adjust the column width to its contents? More generally, is there a place where I can learn more about F# and Interop?

Comment: @Soldalma I've added to my answer the illustration of column width auto adjustment. As to `F# and Interop in general` - for me it concentrates on more interesting aspects, like in [Seamless interoperation with .NET libraries](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/completeness-seamless-dotnet-interop/), than on low-level Excel Automation plumbing done in F#. It would not differ much if I use VB or C# instead of F#, just accounts for certain F# specifics, like calling methods on interfaces, casting to static types, etc.

Comment: Thanks again. I read many articles in `F# for Fun and Profit` but was not aware of this one. BTW, I read (and bought) your book too. Great job!

Comment: I really appreciate your support.

Comment: I took a look at the ExcelProvider's examples and in all of them one gets value from the spreadsheet. In no case one sets a value in the spreadsheet or sets properties like column width. Based on my experience with other type providers they can only be used to get data from the source. Am I wrong in assuming this?

Comment: @Soldalma - The implemented `ExcelProvider` abilities are defined by some equilibrium of the feature demand and the implementation complexity. The main purpose of `ExcelProvider` as the member
 of `FSharp.Data` data access library is to simplify access to data packaged into Excel format, which it achieves. If the mass demand would have place for data packaged into visually 
compelling Excel documents, it would be no doubt addressed by a matching implementation.